# How do I make this animation move from right to left?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I have been learning some JavaScript and this was one of the exercises. It works just fine, but one of the challenges was to make the animation go from right to left and I have been stuck in there for a while. I'm sure is really simple but everything I have tried just doesn't work

```js
"use strict";

var Test = {
  canvas: undefined,
  canvasContext: undefined,
  rectanglePosition: 0
};

Test.start = function() {
  Test.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  Test.canvasContext = Test.canvas.getContext("2d");
  Test.mainLoop();
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Test.start);
Test.update = function() {
  var d = new Date();
  Test.rectanglePosition = d.getTime() % Test.canvas.width;
};
Test.draw = function() {
  Test.canvasContext.fillStyle = "green";
  Test.canvasContext.fillRect(Test.rectanglePosition, 100, 50, 50);

};
Test.mainLoop = function() {
  Test.clearCanvas();
  Test.update();
  Test.draw();
  window.setTimeout(Test.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};

Test.clearCanvas = function() {
  Test.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, Test.canvas.width, Test.canvas.height);
};
```

```html
<div id="testArea">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This line needs to change. Right now, the X is being made positive, but you need to make it negative to go left: `Test.rectanglePosition = d.getTime() % Test.canvas.width;` Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by changing your `Test.update` function.

Currently you are looking at seconds of `d` and dividing it by the width of the screen and grabbing the remainder. With the remainder you are determining the horizontal position of your square.

If you set a variable `i` and `direction` outside of the update function and adjust `i` each update with the direction (+ or -) until you reach either 0 or the width of the screen you should be able to get it to go back and forth... Check out the update:

```js
"use strict";

var Test = {
  canvas: undefined,
  canvasContext: undefined,
  rectanglePosition: 0
};
var i = 0; //current location of the square
var direction = 1; //1 if we are going right, -1 if we are going left

Test.start = function() {
  Test.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  Test.canvasContext = Test.canvas.getContext("2d");
  Test.mainLoop();
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Test.start);
Test.update = function() {
  //var d = new Date();
  //Test.rectanglePosition = d.getTime() % Test.canvas.width;
 
  if (i <= 0) {
     direction = 1;
  } else if (i >= (Test.canvas.width - 50)) {
     //Text.canvas.width - 50 is how far you can go to the 
     //right without running the square off the screen
     //(since 50 is the width of the square)
     direction = -1;
  }
  i += direction;
  Test.rectanglePosition = i;
};
Test.draw = function() {
  Test.canvasContext.fillStyle = "green";
  Test.canvasContext.fillRect(Test.rectanglePosition, 100, 50, 50);

};
Test.mainLoop = function() {
  Test.clearCanvas();
  Test.update();
  Test.draw();
  window.setTimeout(Test.mainLoop, 1000 / 60);
};

Test.clearCanvas = function() {
  Test.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, Test.canvas.width, Test.canvas.height);
};
```

```html
<div id="testArea">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this is more than I wanted, I'm sure this will be useful for me later, I found the solution by myself [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtCoder/xet9dpg7/4/)